# Theory: Buffered video download and delay

Tags: video, download

Could someone please explain me the way it works? My understanding below, may have mistakes.

We have two ways of downloading a movie and watching it at the same time:
1) Buffered
2) Non-buffered

In the first case we are downloading as much data as we are capable of (simply depends on the speed of our internet provider assures). In the second case we are downloading as much data as we need to watch a movie from a certain point - in other words in one second, we download 1 second of the movie.

Next - delay. My professor says there is no difference between buffered and non-buffered download of a movie - a potential delay is the same. How could it be?

So could someone please tell me if the above is true/how it works? And second part: what impact has buffered download on delays?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of 'delay' in this context. What is being delayed?

Comment: Delay in terms of receiving data, downloading them from the internet.

Comment: Sorry, But I don't understand in this context. Do you mean the amount of time it takes from when you press play to when the first frame is displayed on the screen? From a network perspective the server has no concept of buffer, It well respond to the request with the same efficiency no matter what the client does with it.